# Codeigniter not uploading video to server but directory is been created

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

> Hello people, i have a file that does upload video to server but when
>   tested on my localhost, it work perfectly well but when i move over to
>   the server, only the directory is been created but the video is not be
>   uploaded.

so the below code does get any file type (only the Permitted) and convert them into .flv file and then upload them to the server and then store the name to database.

> And another thing am facing is that when i click to upload video file,
>   it does come around with success message but no errors is reported

```
public function submit_file(){
        $err_msgs   ='';
        if($this->input->post('submit')){  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('course_id','search term','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lesson_name','search term','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('file_name','search term','required');
            $course_id          =$this->input->post('course_id');
            $lesson_name            =$this->input->post('lesson_name');
            $real_file_name         =$this->input->post('file_name');
            $course_name            =$this->Course->get_course_name($course_id);
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['alert']  ='<p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Some Filled Were Not filled</p>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('alert',$data['alert']);
                redirect('Create_course/upload_lesson');
            }else{
                //create Dictory for course_name
                $course_name_url    =@ereg_replace(" ","_","$course_name");
                $lesson_name_url    =@ereg_replace(" ","_","$lesson_name");

                @mkdir('__course_file/'.$course_name_url);
                @mkdir('__course_file/'.$course_name_url.'/lesson');
                @mkdir('__course_file/'.$course_name_url.'/lesson/'.$lesson_name_url);



                $config['upload_path'] = './__course_file/'.$course_name_url.'/lesson/'.$lesson_name_url;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'mov|mpeg|mp3|avi|mp4|wmv|mpg';
                $config['max_size']= '';
                $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
                $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    // If there is any error
                    $err_msgs = '<p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$this->upload->display_errors().'</p>';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('alert',$err_msgs);

                }else{
                    //convert file to .flv extension
                    $data=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $video_path = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

                    $directory_path      = $data['upload_data']['file_path'];
                    $directory_path_full      = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                    $file_name      = $data['upload_data']['raw_name'];

                    // ffmpeg command to convert video

                    exec("ffmpeg -i ".$directory_path_full." ".$directory_path.$file_name.".flv");
                    // $file_name is same file name that is being uploaded but you can give your custom video name after converting So use something like myfile.flv.
                    $name   = $this->upload->data('full_path');
                    unlink($name);
                    /// In the end update video name in DB
                    $file_path  =$this->upload->data('full_path');
                    $file_name  =$this->upload->data('raw_name').'.flv';
                    $insert =$this->Course->insert_lesson($course_name,$lesson_name,$file_path,$course_name_url,$lesson_name_url,$file_name,$real_file_name);
                    if($insert  ==TRUE){
                        $data['alert']  ='<p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your Course Has been Created</p>';
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert',$data['alert']);
                    }else{
                        $data['alert']  ='<p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Database Busy, Could not Create Course, Pls Try Again Later!</p>';
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert',$data['alert']);
                    }
                }
                redirect('Create_course/upload_lesson');
            }
        }else{
            $data['alert']  ='<p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Please use the form to submit file</p>';
            $this->session->set_flashdata('alert',$data['alert']);
            redirect('Create_course/upload_lesson');
        }
    }
```

Every thing here does work on my localhost

Comment: any errors ?????

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: after this `$err_msgs` line add `print_r( $err_msgs)die;` and post the data

Comment: ok, let me try that out

Comment: respond quickly ....